# HTML Form and JavaScript validation isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

JavaScript validation not occurring correctly. Form submits anyway without checking the issue

I've tried changing from
`getElementByID.value;`
and `document.form[][].value;`

Tried changing my javascript to do it on my function `init()`;
but also in HTML obsubmit attribute.

Really confused on what im doing wrong

```js
function regValidate() {
  var errMsg = document.getElementById("errMsg");
  var username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
  errMsg.style.padding = "10px";
  var emailRE = "@";
  var email = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
  if (email.match(emailRE) || email.length < 6) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email";
    return false;
  } else if (username.length < 5) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid username";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="register" action="(this is a realwebsite, removing due to privacy + legal reasons)" onsubmit="return regValidate()" method="post">
  <p>
    <h1 class="form--title">Register</h1>
  </p>
  <div id="errMsg"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="username">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" /><br>
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
  </p>
```

There is no error message it just goes straight to the form page which displays what was submitted for what name attribute...

Comment: `return regValidate(e)` there's no variable `e`, it should be `event`.

Comment: And the `regValidate()` function is missing the `e` parameter.

Comment: The function doesn't have `return false;` when the username validation fails.

Comment: I put the event in there after following a different stackoverflow tutorial, i removed both it and it still doesnt work

Comment: Oooh thats a good point for the username field, however, i was testing with an email length less than 6 and it was still not working

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? `document.getElementById("Username").value;` should have caused an error.

Comment: Why are you  using `if...else` to test for your validation conditions? Only one condition will be tested for all the time and never the two.

Comment: maybe you should have a look on my late and more complete answer (below)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `e.preventDefault()`, you just need to use `return false` in all the validation failures.

`getElementById("Username")` should be `getElementById("username")`, since IDs are case-sensitive.

Your email regexp test is backwards, you want to report an error if it *doesn't* match.

```js
function regValidate() {
  var errMsg = document.getElementById("errMsg");
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  errMsg.style.padding = "10px";
  var emailRE = "@";
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  if (!email.match(emailRE) || email.length < 6) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email";
    return false;
  } else if (username.length < 5) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid username";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="register" action="(this is a realwebsite, removing due to privacy + legal reasons)" onsubmit="return regValidate()" method="post">
  <p>
    <h1 class="form--title">Register</h1>
  </p>
  <div id="errMsg"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="username">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" /><br>
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code:

```
function regValidate() {
  var errMsg = document.getElementById("errMsg");
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  errMsg.style.padding = "10px";
  var emailRE = "@";
  var email = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
  if (email.match(emailRE) || email.length < 6) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email";
  } else if (username.length < 5) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid username";
  }

  return false;
}
```

I removed function argument and added `return false` so form submit action doesn't happen. Also fixed uppercase Username to username to match your html

Only thing changed in html is onsubmit function call to have no arguments as 
 it was removed from javascript:

```
<form name="register" action="(this is a realwebsite, removing due to privacy + legal reasons)" onsubmit="return regValidate()" method="post">
  <p>
    <h1 class="form--title">Register</h1>
  </p>
  <div id="errMsg"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="username">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" /><br>
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
  </p>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should have a look on this code:

```js
const MyForm   = document.querySelector('form[name=register]')
    , ErrorMsg = document.querySelector('#errMsg')

ErrorMsg.style.padding = "10px";  // better to do this with some CSS
const emailRE = "@";              // see regex for futur ?

MyForm.onsubmit=e=>  // regValidate()
{
  e.preventDefault()  // just for testing here 

  if (!MyForm.email.value.match(emailRE) || MyForm.email.value.length < 6)
  {
    ErrorMsg.textContent = "Please enter a valid email";
    return false;
  }
  if (MyForm.username.value.length < 5) {
    ErrorMsg.textContent = "Please enter a valid username";
    return false;
  }

  console.log('form is OK')
}
MyForm.onreset=_=>
{
  MyForm.email.style.width    = '110px'
  MyForm.username.style.width = '140px'
  ErrorMsg.innerHTML          = '&nbsp;'
}

MyForm.email.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.style.width = `${(this.value.length +1) *8}px`
})
MyForm.username.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.style.width = `${(this.value.length +1) *8}px`
})
```

```html
<form name="register" action="XXX" method="post" >
  <p>
    <h1 class="form--title">Register</h1>
  </p>
  <div id="errMsg">&nbsp;</div>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" style="width:110px" value="" >
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="username">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" style="width:140px" value="" >
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">submit</button><br>
    <button type="reset">reset</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i changes a few lines your codes, you can't use e.preventDefault() in onsubmit event, because you used "return reg Validate()". its waited bool variable from regValidate()

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

<form name="register" action="(this is a realwebsite, removing due to privacy + legal reasons)" onsubmit="return regValidate()" method="post">
  <p>
    <h1 class="form--title">Register</h1>
  </p>
  <div id="errMsg"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="username">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" /><br>
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
  </p>
  </form>

<script>
function regValidate() {
  var errMsg = document.getElementById("errMsg");
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  errMsg.style.padding = "10px";
  var emailRE = "@";
  var email = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
  if (email.match(emailRE) || email.length < 6) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email";
    return false;
  } else if (username.length < 5) {
    errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid username";
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the validation?

Comment: Sorry i forget that, i added my post

Comment: You should explain what was wrong with the original code, and how your answer fixes it. But your code is completely different, it's hard to see how it really applies.

Comment: hmm, okay i changed my post